# Plotting irregular time-series (multiple) from dataframe using ggplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, python-ggplot

I have a df structured as so:

```
   UnitNo        Time           Sensor
0   1.0   2016-07-20 18:34:44    19.0
1   1.0   2016-07-20 19:27:39    19.0
2   3.0   2016-07-20 20:45:39    17.0
3   3.0   2016-07-20 23:05:29    17.0
4   3.0   2016-07-21 01:23:30    11.0
5   2.0   2016-07-21 04:23:59    11.0
6   2.0   2016-07-21 17:33:29    2.0
7   2.0   2016-07-21 18:55:04    2.0
```

I want to create a time-series plot where each `UnitNo` has its own line (color) and the y-axis values correspond to `Sensor` and the x-axis is `Time`. I want to do this in `ggplot`, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do this efficiently. I have looked at previous examples but they all have regular time series, i.e., observations for each variable occur at the same times which makes it easy to create a time index. I imagine I can loop through and add data to plot(?), but I was wondering if there was a more efficient/elegant way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Time').groupby('UnitNo').Sensor.plot();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. You seem to help me out everyday! I am a convert from Matlab and python/pandas takes some getting used to, so you'll probably see me around some more :-)

Comment: Hello @jtam glad I could help out.  We're fortunate to have several really good folks answering pandas questions... jezrael obviously one of them :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.pivot('Time', 'UnitNo','Sensor').plot()
```

Or:

```
df.set_index(['Time', 'UnitNo'])['Sensor'].unstack().plot()
```

[image: graph]

If some duplicates:

```
df = df.groupby(['Time', 'UnitNo'])['Sensor'].mean().unstack().plot()
df = df.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='UnitNo',values='Sensor', aggfunc='mean').plot()
```

Comment: Thanks for this jezrael! I favor piR's answer a bit more just because I am more familiar with the `groupby` command than the `pivot` and `unstack` commands. But, I'll have to take a closer look at those soon.

Comment: No problem, obviously for one questions are multilple good answers. Good luck!